# Downsample signal with nan values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I am trying to downsample time series data using [`scipy.signal.decimate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.decimate.html).  My data has NaN values so the result is an array with just NaN values.  I think this is actually a result of the lowpass filter the algorithm applies before decimating the data.

How do I appropriately handle the NaN values?  I have considered throwing out the NaN values but I need some data for each time step.  I am leaning toward using the average of the nearest non-NaN values, though I don't know if there are negative consequences of this naive approach.  Is there an option to ignore the them, similar to [`np.nanmean()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html)?

Comment: you can always filter your data using a mask, i.e. `data[~np.isnan(data)]`

Comment: Add representative sample data and expected output?

Comment: If you check the source, none of the filtering functions that `scipy.decimate` uses internally (depending on array dimensions and the specified `ftype`) support masking of NaNs. I think it would also be quite an effort to do so as you would need to correct each value near a NaN depending on the window function and the relative position to the one or more NaNs in the neighborhood. So yeah, if you want to filter before downsampling, I think you would need to substitute the NaNs with some fill value depending on the nearest non-NaNs.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that if your downsampling factor is large, the lowpass filter doesn't actually do much, so you could just reshape and then apply `np.nanmean` over the new dimension.